# My setNumber isn't changing accordingly with what I expected

Tags: java, class, getter-setter

I'm trying to set a number into a class, something like this

```
public class Governador extends Candidato{
    private int numero;
    private static int limite_inferior = 77;

    public Governador(String nome, String partido, int numero) {
        super(nome, partido);
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        if (numero > 99 || numero < limite_inferior) {
            this.numero = limite_inferior;
            limite_inferior++;
        }
        this.numero = numero;
    }
}
```

But when I get a number like 42, it doesn't turn into 77 like I was wishing for. It's probably something really easy, but I'm blind right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is fairly simple. You are **always** setting the input number.

```
if (numero > 99 || numero < limite_inferior) {
    this.numero = limite_inferior;
    limite_inferior++;
}

this.numero = numero; //HERE
```

No matter if it enters or not on the IF it will set the number given. So add an else condition like:

```
if (numero > 99 || numero < limite_inferior) {
    this.numero = limite_inferior;
    limite_inferior++;
}else{
    this.numero = numero;
}
```

Comment: Or move above the if statement

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with the code you call this class or the `Candidato` class, probably an overriding code. Post it on your question and I will see if there are anything more on it. To the code you shown and by what you said just this fix would be enough.

Comment: after your hint I found what I was doing wrong, I was calling a constructor with the number argument in, so it haven't even passed through the `setNumero` .

Comment: Great that I could help :)